# How do I add client certificates in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have two services. One service (Service 1) is going to be called by the client, utilize some internal proprietary authorization system, and then, if the client is authorized, pass the entire message on to another service. Service 2 will be secured with SSL and SSL will need to pass a certificate.

In Web API, I'm utilizing a DelegatingHandler, but the HttpRequestMessage class does not appear to have any way to add a certificate to the request. How do I do I take the HttpRequestMessage coming in to Service 1 and add a certificate so that it can then be passed to Service 2.

Comment: Who's going to call Service2? If it's Service1, I believe you're mixing SSL with Mutual authentication. If it's the client, adding client's certificate doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Service 1 is calling Service 2.